# Find a string in MySQL table through a loop in multiple arrays

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am using WordPress, and I need to create a function to check for typos in a custom table, by comparing the single values with a comparison table. The values to be checked are animal species names, and they stored as follows in table A

```
id | qualifying_species
----------------------
1  | Dugong dugon, Delphinus delphis
2  | Balaneoptera physalus, Tursiops truncatus, Stenella coeruleoalba
```

etc.

These values must be checked for typos by matching them with table B which contains a simple list of species name as a reference

```
id | species_name
----------------------
1  | Dugong dugon 
2  | Delphinus delphis
3  | Balaneoptera physalus
4  | Tursiops truncatus
5  | Stenella coeruleoalba
```

Here's the code I prepared

```
function test(){
global $wpdb;
$query_species = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT qualifying_species FROM A", ARRAY_A);

                    foreach($query_species as $row_species)
                    {
                        $string = implode (";", $row_species);
                        $qualifying_species = explode(";", $string);

                        //echo '<pre>';
                        //print_r($qualifying_species);
                        //echo '</pre>';

                        foreach ($qualifying_species as $key => $value) {
                            //I get here the single species name
                            echo $value . '<br>';
                                //I compare the single name with the species list table
                                $wpdb->get_results("SELECT COUNT(species_name) as num_rows FROM B WHERE species_name = '$value'");
                                    //if the species is written correctly, it will be counted as 1 with num_rows
                                    //if the species is written wrongly, no match will be found and num_rows = 0 
                                    echo $wpdb->num_rows . '<br>';
                        }
                    } 
}
```

The echo was to check the results of the function. The Mysql query works when I do it on PHPMyAdmin, but it seems that something is wrong with the PHP loop that I wrote. For each `$value` echoed I have a result of 1 echoed with  `$wpdb->num_rows` even if `$value` presents typos or doesn't exist in table B

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `$string = implode (";", $row_species); $qualifying_species = explode(";", $string);` – what’s the point in _that_? And why am I not seeing any exploding of the `qualifying_species` value by `', '` anywhere? If you wanted to compare the values from that “list” to individual values, then I’d assume it _starts_ with that …?

Comment: Do it on MySQL level, not in PHP - this will be more effective.

Comment: Recommendation - do not store the value as CSV, normalize your data.

Comment: To @CBroe, that was my mistake in writing the post: actually the values are stored in with a semicolon (;).

Comment: @Akina, unfortunately data will come via csv as they are output in that way and will be uploaded in a MySQL table. I don't understand your comment to do it on MYsql level. Sorry I am not an expert with Mysql

Comment: What is precise MySQL version?

Comment: MySQL 5.7.26: I am testing the function on a local MAMP

Comment: What is maximal species amount per one `qualifying_species` CSV value? Is it possible when one `species_name` value is a substring of another `species_name` value?

Comment: Up to now is 600, but it will double easily or triple in a future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solutoin for MySQL 5.7.

Create a procedure (must be performed only once):

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE check_table_data ()
BEGIN
DECLARE sp_name VARCHAR(255);
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT species_name FROM tableB;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done := TRUE;
OPEN cur;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t_tableA SELECT * FROM tableA;
FETCH cur INTO sp_name;
REPEAT
    UPDATE t_tableA SET qualifying_species = REPLACE(qualifying_species, sp_name, '');
    FETCH cur INTO sp_name;
UNTIL done END REPEAT;
CLOSE cur;
SELECT id, qualifying_species wrong_species FROM t_tableA WHERE REPLACE(qualifying_species, ',', '') != '';
DROP TABLE t_tableA;
END
```

Now, when you need to check your data for unknown species and misprintings you simply execute one tiny query

```
CALL check_table_data;
```

which will return `id` for a row which have a species value not found in `tableB`, and this species itself.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=ade293f41a23e651cdfa8c1bc036a5c7)

The code assumes that there is no `species_name` value which is a substring of another `species_name` value.

---

The procedure do the next: it makes the data copy then removes existent species from the values. If some species is wrong (is absent, contains misprint) it won't be removed. After all species processed the procedure selects all rows which are not empty (contain non-removed species).

Comment: Thanks I am going to try your option. Since I am not experienced with Mysql, where I create the procedure? and where I call it? I normally write my custom functions in the file functions.php of my WordPress. I am not sure where to write it

Comment: *where I create the procedure?* It is created on MySQL server within the database. The best way is to create it using MySQL console client. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html (pay attention to DELIMITER statements). But you may use Workbench, phpMyAdmin and so on - it doesn't matter. *where I call it?* in your PHP code, `$wpdb->get_results("CALL check_table_data;");`

Comment: Just one more question @Akina, as I didn't find how to solve it. If in my qualifying species field I have values with 3 words, such as "Balaenoptera musculus intermedia", the procedure reports the last word (in this case "intermedia") as wrong, while it is not. I tried to go through your suggested procedure, but as I am not an expert I didn't find the way to solve this.

Comment: @ElenaPoliti I cannot reproduce. The code does not depend on the words amount. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=26630e435ce17bc5a7702b51761fc5baEdit fiddle, add your data (and maybe use your tables structures) and provide the link which demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Here's what I mean: check table A first row (Delphinus delphis delphis) https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=6b18e3ff1172bf39862a71f38f46d850

Comment: @ElenaPoliti o_O Please read my answer one more time. Especially the sentence under the link to the fiddle...

Comment: Yes sorry. here's the fiddle with original data https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=7262dc6d7a3d4728f99980c0b62a5c6f . I don't understand: on the fiddle the procedure works correctly. However in my MAMP database the temporary table shows results as: record "4 - maui" and record "5 - Unconfirmed". The word maui being part of the species name with 3 words. the same bug comes for all the 3-words names present in my imma_database table. I will figure it out

Comment: @ElenaPoliti Check - this word in species list may contain a symbol which is only visually the same as a letter in the species name (or backward). Look `HEX(column)` and compare.

Answer (score 0):

You maybe could do this in the same query :

```
SELECT *
FROM table_a
INNER JOIN table_b ON FIND_IN_SET(species_name,replace(qualifying_species,';',','))
```

if you want to find non-existent values, use something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_b
LEFT OUTER JOIN table_a ON FIND_IN_SET(species_name,replace(qualifying_species,';',','))
WHERE table_a.id IS null
```

Comment: Pay attention - the CSV values contains a space after a comma. Single FIND_IN_SET will find nothing.

Comment: if there is a space after the comma, juste have to add it in the replace no?

Comment: Maybe.. but there can be values without space, with 2 spaces, with trailing space(s) in theory.. FIND_IN_SET can use only the data which is strictly formatted - but OP tells that typos/misprints may occur, i.e. the value may be direct user input (or grabbing result) which is unpredictable...